# Which Django template layout is better?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Which layout is better(Django 1.4+),:

```
project/templates/base.html
# project/templates/app/base.html # overriding some_app at project level, optional
project/app/templates/app/base_app.html
project/app/templates/app/base_app_index.html
```

- base_app_index.html extends base_app.html -- app level
- base_app.html extends base.html -- project level.

or [usable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/reusable-apps/) like this(no share between apps with one project)

```
project/app/templates/app/base_app.html
project/app/templates/app/base_app_index.html
```

- just base_app_index.html extends base_app.html

References:

From [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance):

- Create a base.html template that holds the main look-and-feel of your site.
- Create a base_SECTIONNAME.html template for each “section” of your site. For example, base_news.html, base_sports.html. These templates all extend base.html and include section-specific styles/design.
- Create individual templates for each type of page, such as a news article or blog entry. These templates extend the appropriate section template.

From [Django Best Pratices](http://lincolnloop.com/django-best-practices/projects.html):

> Location Templates typically live in one of two places, inside the
>   application or at the root level of a project. We recommend keeping
>   all your templates in the project template directory unless you plan
>   on including your application in multiple projects (or developing it
>   as a open source “reusable” application). In that case, it can be
>   helpful to ship with a set of sample templates in the application,
>   allowing it to work out-of-the-box or serving as an example for other
>   developers.

From [Two Scoops of Django](https://django.2scoops.org/):

- Each app has a base_.html template. App-level base templates share a common parent, base.html.
- Templates within apps share a common parent base_.html template.
- Any template at the same level as base.html inherits base.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It likely depends on your purposes. For *most* purposes, the first example will work best. Your `base.html` will include a lot of site-specific stuff that you won't want to repeat across each and every `base_app.html` template.

If you are making reusable apps that you want to share with other people, then it's probably best to use the second example. This way someone that uses your app won't need a `base.html` template to get your app up and running. It's a little more "all-inclusive".

This is basically what those docs are saying. The general advice is use the first method *unless* you're open-sourcing it and putting it on PyPi or something.

Even if you want to make a package reusable for your use only (i.e. use in multiple projects you're working on), I'd go with the first method. You can make it so you always have a `base.html` in your template directory.

Comment: OK, if I want to make it reusable, I could copy base.html into the app's template directory. Thanks, I will go with the first one.

Comment: You could do that too, but base.html might include a lot of site-specific layout that won't necessarily translate to a reusable app. The best result would likely include a lot of your content in template `{% block %}` tags that would allow easier customization for app users.